# How do I get data from text field in php file in Javascript file with ajax and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm creating a plugin and I created a text field and I want to pull the data of the text field in my JavaScript file.

```
function my_plugin_plugin_html(){?>
    
    <div id="wrap container">
        <h3 id="eylo"> Plugin Header </h3>
    
     <form method="post" action='options.php'>
        <?php settings_errors(); ?>
        <?php settings_fields('my_plugin_option_group'); ?>
        <label for="jquery-field">select field ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="jquery-field" id="jquery-field" value="<?php echo get_option('jquery-field');?> ">
        <?php submit_button();?>
        <h2 id="jquery-field-value">This is the value: <?php echo get_option('jquery-field');?></h2>
    <?php 

}
```

I have created already the fields but I don't succeed to pull the data with jQuery and ajax (my files already connected with the website).

Comment: Do you want a `jquery-field` from some other page? then you can use ajax for it and send the field to this php file using `$.post()`